# Sql Query for Identified by duplicates and remove in it

Tags: sql

```
SELECT i.product_id, o.date_added 
FROM ims_order_product i 
   INNER JOIN ims_order o 
WHERE  i.product_id IN (SELECT p.product_Id FROM ims_product p)
```

The Query Return  Product_id column and Date column But Product_id column contain duplicates So I want remove duplicates in Product_id based on Date_added by recent Date Can any give the answer.

Comment: Add sample data and expected ouput

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: The query is invalid, you are missing a JOIN condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM (SELECT i.product_id, o.date_added, o.order_id FROM `ims_order_product` i 
JOIN `ims_order` o ON o.order_id = i.order_id
JOIN `ims_product` pr ON pr.product_id = i.product_id ORDER BY date_added DESC) AS sub GROUP BY product_id

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by product_id. Below query will select the latest date for duplicate product_id

```
SELECT i.product_id, MAX(o.date_added) FROM ims_order_product i INNER JOIN ims_order o WHERE i.product_id IN (SELECT p.product_Id FROM ims_product p) GROUP BY i.product_id
```

Comment: but that query running all dates are same, because that column taken by max date so we have to operate on date based on product id

Comment: There is a `group by` clause in the end. So the MAX date will give maximum date for each product id and all dates will not be same if you have different max dates for different product ids

Comment: No group by applied by last first they had set all product id same date as per max of date, So  we have solve by above query

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query

```
SELECT i.product_id, MAX(o.date_added) date_added
FROM ims_order_product i 
INNER JOIN ims_order o --add your join condition here
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.product_Id FROM ims_product p WHERE p.product_Id = i.product_id)
GROUP BY i.product_id
```